# How to override a css file inside node_modules

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm, node-modules

I need to modify a css file from dependency, located in "node_modules". But when I do "npm install", it will overwrite everything that I modified in the css files from the node module.

Is there something to prevent this overwrite and and keep the modification that I've made in the node modules

Comment: its bad idea to modify anything in node module, you can create your own css in your project and import it in your html or js (front-end).

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this, patching files from node_modules is in general a very bad idea. Either fork their project and make a private npm package with the modified css file, or modify the file after install with postinstall. It's still not recommended since the class names can be modified in later builds or required styling can change making it not usable, so the first option is the best.